# I am trying to close last fragment in series of three fragments ,but it takes a while to close it and return to previous activity

Tags: android

logic is as shown below:

A(activity)- B(Activity) .
B has three fragments ---->    X-Y-Z.

and my code for back pressing is shown below:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    Log.i("backcount", String.valueOf(backStackCount));
    if (backStackCount == 0) {
        finish();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
 }
```

Now when fragment X is closed count will be zero and B(Activity) will be finished and A(Activity) will be loaded, but it takes a while to return back to A , and meanwhile white screen is shown, I don't understand what's happening wrong

Comment: Probably has something to do with your Activity A onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The reason why it was showing, because X,Y and Z fragments were added to stack via addToBackStack(). But X should not be added but only Y and Z fragments should be added via addToBackStack()